# how to fix 'Class App\Http\Controllers\Productcontroller does not exist'

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

i recive this error

> "\Controllers\ProductController does not exist "

but indeed i have this controller in my `app/http/controller`

```
class ProductController extends AdminController {
  public function index() {
    $products=Product::latest()->paginate(20);
    return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));
  }
}
.....

Route::get('/admin/product','Productcontroller@index');
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe check your namespace and see if changing that directory suited with the error will help.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin
```

Directs to the Admin Folder in the Controllers Folder

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

Uses the main Controller.php file

After all this you can check your routes if they work at this point.
If you want to extend another controller instead of the main controller like in your case, I think you should check the directory of the AdminController.php and use the Use command again if the directory isn't in your namespace directory.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers

use App\Http\Controllers\admin\AdminController
```

Atleast that's where i think the extent of your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Route::get('/admin/product','Productcontroller@index');
```

should probably be (watch the case):

```
 Route::get('/admin/product','ProductController@index');
```

Also make sure that you import the right namespace: Is your controller really living in **App\Http\Controllers** namespace ?